# How to use both variables inside one function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I used AJAX for the real time passing of data. So far, here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var packages = $('#packageselect').val();
    if (packages == '6') {
        $('.opttnx').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.opttnx').css('display', 'none');
    }

    var email = $('#exampleInputEmail1').val();
    var tnxpack = $('#tankselect').val();
    var nameClient = $('#custname').val();
    var transac = $('#transac').val();
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var chooseweb = $('#chooseweb').val();
    var datum = {
        email: email,
        packages: packages,
        tnxpack: tnxpack,
        username: nameClient,
        transac: transac,
        amount: amount,
        date: date,
        chooseweb: chooseweb
    }

    $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'email/viewEmail', 
        data: datum,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#viewemail').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
public function viewEmail() {
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $packages = $_GET['packages'];
    $tnxpack = $_GET['tnxpack'];
    $amount = $_GET['amount'];
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $chooseweb = $_GET['chooseweb'];
    $transac = $this->search_model->getTransac($_GET['transac'],$date);
    $message = $this->search_model->getPackageView($packages, $username, $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->type, $tnxpack, $transac, $amount, $chooseweb);
    echo $message;
}
```

This is how I call it in my `viewer.php`:

````
public function getTransac($transacChose) {
    $transaction = "";
    $transaction2 = "";

    if ($transacChose == '1') {
        $transaction = "and sample";
        $transaction2 = "and sample2";
    }
}

 ``` //this is how i call my transac.
 This is a sample sentence ". $transac . "; ```
````

Can someone help me? It's a little bit confusing for me right now because I', not using an array to store two variables in my method.

Should I do it like this?

`This is a sample sentence ". $transac[1] .";`

Comment: What is your expected output? Your question is not enough clear.

Comment: its okay now i've solved it

Comment: Great, do post answer so it might help to other visitors.

Comment: wait i'm guessing its right . haha wait

Comment: nah still the wrong one\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding another variable into my ajax

`var transac = $('#transac').val();`

and on my php

`$transac2 = $this->search_model->getTransac2($_GET['transac']);`

that's all . hahaha i know i know its a newbie move but still works :)

Answer (score 0):

declare all var outside the function

Example :

```
var packages;

function myFunction(){
   packages = $('#packageselect').val();
}
```

Comment: this can't help.